# Using one mixin from LESS within another mixin

Tags: css, styles, less, mixins

I am trying to use a mix that calculates the base line height in another that contains my base font styles. Each time I try to compile, I get an error.

Here is an example.

```
.lineHeight(@sizeValue){
@remValue: @sizeValue;
@pxValue: (@sizeValue * 10);
line-height: ~"@{pxValue}px";
line-height: ~"@{remValue}rem";
}

.baseFont(@weight: normal, @size: 14px, @lineHeight: (.lineHeight(2.1)) {
font-family: @fontFamily;
font-size: @size;
font-weight: @weight;
line-height: @lineHeight;
}
```

The error is:
TypeError: Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined
    at getLocation (/Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/less/lib/less/parser.js:212:34)
    at new LessError (/Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/less/lib/less/parser.js:221:19)
    at Object.toCSS (/Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/less/lib/less/parser.js:385:31)
    at /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/less/bin/lessc:107:28
    at /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/less/lib/less/parser.js:434:40
    at /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/less/lib/less/parser.js:94:48
    at /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/less/lib/less/index.js:116:17
    at /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/less/lib/less/parser.js:434:40
    at /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/less/lib/less/parser.js:94:48
    at /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/less/lib/less/index.js:116:17

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to call a mixin from the argument list of another (aside from the facet that you have an extra `(` before you call the mixin).

This is my attempt at mixin inheritance, which works for your situation, but isn't the most elegant LESS I've seen. The default values for weight and size also need to be repeated in two places:

```
.lineHeight(@sizeValue){
    @remValue: @sizeValue;
    @pxValue: (@sizeValue * 10);
    line-height: ~"@{pxValue}px";
    line-height: ~"@{remValue}rem";
}

// Shared by both versions of baseFont, never used directly
.commonBaseFont(@weight, @size) {
    font-family: @fontFamily;
    font-size: @size;
    font-weight: @weight;
}

// baseFont called without lineHeight argument
.baseFont(@weight: normal, @size: 14px){
    .commonBaseFont(@weight, @size);
    .lineHeight(2.1)
}

// baseFont called with lineHeight argument
.baseFont(@weight: normal, @size: 14px, @lineHeight) {
    .commonBaseFont(@weight, @size);
    line-height: @lineHeight;
}
```